# Adding multiple content in TabBarView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to make multiple contents in a TabBarView of flutter like adding a mini instruction and a start button to navigate to the game screen but it keeps giving me error like the

> "Error: No named parameter with the name 'children'"

here's my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'DiceHome.dart';
import 'HclcHome.dart';
import 'HotHome.dart';
import 'JnpHome.dart';
import 'icons.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Pocket Money:'),
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(MyFlutterApp.dice)), //DiceTab
                Tab(icon: Icon(MyFlutterApp.hand)), //JnPTab
                Tab(icon: Icon(MyFlutterApp.clovers_card)), //HclcTab
                Tab(icon: Icon(MyFlutterApp.coins)), //HotTab
              ], //tabs
            ), //TabBar
          ), //appbar
          drawer: Drawer(), //drawer
          body: TabBarView(
            children: const <Widget>[
              Center(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Dice Game',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30.0,
                    ), //TextStyle
                  ), //Text
                  SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                  Text(
                    'Guess the next roll of the dice',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ), //TextStyle
                  ), //Text
                  Text(
                    'If you guessed right yo win',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ), //TextStyle
                  ), //Text
                  SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                ], //Children
              ), //Center,
              Center(child: Text('loading...')), //Center
              Center(child: Text('loading...')), //Center
              Center(child: Text('loading...')), //Center
            ], //children
          ), //TabBarView
        ), //Scaffold
      ), //DefaultTabController
    ); //MaterialApp
  } //build
}
```

My goal is to make an app with multiple mini games with the use of tab bar as my game selector for fewer screen codes, is it possible with tab bar view?

Answer (score 0):

`Center` takes a child (a single widget) not children (a list of widgets). You should use row, column, stack, etc. (any of the widgets that take children) if you wish to display multiple widgets within center. Try this:

```
...
Center(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        'Dice Game',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 30.0,
        ), //TextStyle
      ), //Text
      SizedBox(height: 30.0),
      Text(
        'Guess the next roll of the dice',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15.0,
        ), //TextStyle
      ), //Text
      Text(
        'If you guessed right yo win',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15.0,
        ), //TextStyle
      ), //Text
      SizedBox(height: 30.0),
    ], //Children
  ), //Column
), //Center
...
```